# Schema mapping tools

Tags: xml, mapping, schema

We have two different schema call it internal and external and we would like to map xml from one schema to another?The problem is with xslt that we need maintain lots of xslt mapping.is there any automated tools to help us to achive it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no fully automated schema mapping tools at this time. 
For example Cupid (Microsoft research) is able to semiautomatically map XML schemes, but I do not think that there is a download available...

You can find a general survey article about schema matching [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=767154)